# One model, one view, one controller. Is there any very simple way to show this in an example?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, iis-7

I have searched and read about mvc.  I understand MVC.  I am only stuck on the beginnings.  If I can just get that rolling, I'll be alright to continue.  But as soon as I get going the writer throws in something they don't explain.  Example, they will show a model extends some class, but they never show you that class or don't explain it.  I know this has been asked a bunch on SO, but it seems to degrade into complexity too fast.

Is it possible to just have one model, one controller, and one view and show that as an example?  Am I making it too simple?

I have looked at various premade frameworks, codeigniter, wigbi, skinnymvc, etc.  I do not want to use them right now.  I understand OOP and OOD.  I just can't put this together for whatever reason.  Thanks for anything that shows a model, a controller, a view, one system, three pages, that isn't secretly three gigantic pages that are masquerading as simple, maybe just a select * from users.  I am trying to use PDO if that matters.

Comment: Why are you saying that you understand MVC, while asking for the most basic example possible?

Comment: @tereško understanding something and being able to execute it are two different things.

Comment: @johnny: Oh that is promising to put an answer. So even you can understand the answer, you might not be able to execute it, right?

Comment: @hakre It like the different between theory and application.  "scientists seek to understand what is, while engineers seek to create what never was."  I am at the scientist part right now.  I need to become an engineer.

Comment: there is no theory without application. The application is a proof of your understanding. That other thing is called dream or de-realization.

Comment: Read documentation from any php framework. Everyone has clearly explained what is mvc or hmvc. This question shows lack of research. -1. As for example goes, the best written is in codeigniters documentation though, it does not give the full potential of a model. None the less, it is a good start.

Comment: @itachi , you should not try to learn MVC design pattern from PHP frameworks. That's the worst thing one can do, because every popular framework, that claims to use MVC, actually implements the Rails bastardization of the pattern.

Comment: Well i agree with you. They don't actually shows the real design patterns. But OP said that he knows the design patterns but only need example. So i thought, he could use those examples. If you know the theory, given the tool, you will improvise it applying that theory. If OP doesn't know design patterns, then he should not follow my advice above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest possible example. Do not build an application on this.

```
function model() {
      return array('some'=>'random','prefix'=>'Hello');
}

function view($data) {
      header('content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
      echo "<html><head>title</head><body>",htmlspecialchars($data['greeting']),"</body></html>";
}
function controller() {
      $name = $_GET['name'];
      $modeldata = model();
      $viewdata = array('greeting'=> "{$modeldata['prefix']} {$name}");
      view($viewdata);
}

controller();
```

Comment: you call that MVC? Because that is the beginning letter of the function names or what is the correlation if I may ask?

Comment: @hakre That's great.  I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 4):

Model is not an object or a class, but a layer. It is one of two layers, other being presentation layer (which contains most notably controllers and views). The simplest example would be something like:

```
$serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory( $pdo );
$view =           new FooView( $serviceFactory, $pathToTempaltes );
$controller =     new FooController( $view, $serviceFactory );

$controller->someCommand();
$view->produceResponse();
```

This example assumes extremely simplified model layer, with no abstraction separating domain objects and data abstraction structures.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as 3 sheets of paper stacked in front of each other. The front piece of paper (view) shows the user interface, the back piece of paper (model) is getting information from the database, and the middle piece of paper (controller) is relaying information from the back piece of paper to the front piece of paper.

Comment: With respect, that is what I know.  What I am asking is how to execute it.

Comment: How is this wrong? This is absolutely the way it works.

Comment: @WillemEllis: No, it's not layered. Controller and View are next to each other, see this picture: http://i.imgur.com/ZEjah.jpg

Comment: btw, if you are creating web-only application, then usually the relation between controllers and views will be 1:1.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding your question. Also, I would hope you're not displaying things directly from the controller. If not, I don't see how a view and a controller could be next to each other.

Comment: @WillemEllis: Because they belong to each other. The controller takes the user input, and the view represents what the user to input. You see the circle those two form?

Comment: @WillemEllis , controllers and views are "next to each other" because they are part of presentation layer. Controllers deal with user's input, views handle the interface.

Comment: Okay, I guess I see what you're saying. I use them in this way, but have always visualized it the way I explained.

Comment: It has been a quite common misconception since Rails was released. Actually the model is much more complicated, then you might think. As noted before, it is quite complicated layer. At the same time, the interaction in presentation layer is also strictly defined and the way how information gets from model layer to the view determines whether you are implementing classical MVC, Model2 MVC, MVP or MVVM design pattern.